# Dynamically reload somefile.rb in runtime?

Tags: ruby

I have two Ruby files: exec.rb and lib.rb. lib.rb is required by exec.rb. Every time I modify lib.rb, I need to restart exec.rb.

Is it possible to have exec.rb reload lib.rb while running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can subscribe to file change notifications. Here's a lib for osx: [rb-fsevent](https://github.com/thibaudgg/rb-fsevent).

When you get notification that the file changed, you can reload it.

```
filename = './lib.rb' # get file name from event
load filename
```

You should use `load` instead of `require`, because `require` loads file only once and then does not load it again.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to do this using [`File.mtime`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/File.html#method-c-mtime) and comparing the last-modified timestamp for lib.rb.

In your code, get the `mtime` when you first load the file:

```
last_mtime = File.mtime('lib.rb')
load 'lib.rb'
```

Later, in a loop as you process, check again to see if the modification time changed, and reload if necessary:

```
current_mtime = File.mtime('lib.rb')
if (current_mtime != last_mtime)
  last_mtime = current_mtime
  load 'lib.rb'
end
```

I've used a similar technique in the past, and it worked well. I set mine up so it only checked every five minutes, but your needs might be different.